# knitr skip line in external code

Tags: r, knitr

I am using the knitr package with the option of external code. Is the there a way that I can skip a line in a chunk from being read? For example:

```
## @knitr chunk1
a <- 1:100
## This comment should not appear
## @knitr chunk2
print(a[1:12])
```

In the example above, I would like that the 3rd line will not appear in the final *.pdf. Thanks a lot for any hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. use `<<chunk1, echo=-2>>=` which means you want to exclude the 2nd expression from the [output](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/);
2. put that line in another chunk with another label (`## @knitr go-away`), or without a label at all (`## @knitr`)